# Compilation problem after running bibtex

Tags: bibtex, biblatex, errors, compiling

I'm having the following problem:

My document compiles properly before running bibtex. When I try to recompile after running the bibtex command it gave this compiling error:

```
    Runaway argument?
    \MakeLowercase {os estilos de aprendizaje: procedimientos de diagn\IeC \ETC.
    ! File ended while scanning use of \blx@mkcp@end.
    <inserted text> 
    \par 
    <*> these
```

I checked the bibfile and there is an entry with this title:

```
   @book{alonso1991,
   Address = {Bilbao, Espa{\~n}a},
   Author = {Alonso, C. M. and Gallego, D. J. and Honey, P.},
   Publisher = {Complutense},
   Title = {Los estilos de aprendizaje: procedimientos de diagn{\'\o}stico y mejora},
   Year = {2007}}
```

It seemed ok to me.

I'm using `biblatex`, before using `biblatex` this problem wasn't happening.

Comment: You'll need to give more information than this. The bib record itself is unlikely to be the problem. (Make a simple document which just cites this bib item and prints the bibliography and you should find that it works.) The problem is more likely to be caused by code around where you are doing the `cite` command itself.  Again, make a minimal working document that shows the problem.  Or try removing all the .aux files, latex your file again and then run bibtex again.

Comment: Please always provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/3240). So it's much easier to locate your problem.

Comment: This compiles fine for me. Are you sure you mean `diagn{\'\o}stico`? This compiles as ø with an accent on it...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I try in a new document and it works. I don't how to track what is messing up the things in the large document... thanks for you help!

Comment: Make a copy of your document, comment out more and more code until the problem goes away. Once it has gone away, the last thing you commented out was the problem. If you still can't figure out, update your question with the (hopefully) few lines that are left. Usually the first thing that can go is all of the content.

Comment: With no MWE, this can't reasonably be answered => 'too localized'.